# Comparing unicode characters in Batch

Tags: batch-file, unicode, cmd, windows-10

I have a prompt in Batch which asks for a specific input. The thing is that when you type `;`, I want to exit the script like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P ANSWER="Cancel with ; >"
IF /I [%ANSWER%] EQU [;] EXIT
ECHO "You didn't type ;"
```

But instead of exiting, it says: `[ was unexpected`.

How can I compare a Unicode character with `if`?

Comment: you need quotes and use `==` instead of `equ`, this has nothing to do with unicode.

Comment: Better still, use the choice command for known specific input, please open up a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the 'enter' key, and read th presented information, to learn how to use it correctly.

Comment: `;` (semicolon) is a delimiter in batch scripting (similar to a space) so use double quotes instead of square bracket as `IF /I "%ANSWER%" EQU ";" EXIT`

Comment: Thank you all! I'm so dumb.

Comment: if you are just capturing ***one*** keystroke, better check [this](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7396) out